# How to make HP an instance variable in Pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame, instance-variables

I have the ***EXACT SAME*** problem as this gentleman here: [Health for each enemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630434/health-for-each-enemy), and it seems as though he found an answer that worked for him. However, that answer is for java code and I'm using Pygame, so I do not understand how to apply what they did to my Pygame code.

Does anyone know how to make it so that every enemy in my game does not share the same hp amount? He found out that he needed to make his class variable an instantaneous one but I'm unaware of how to do this.

This is the zombie code. Note how the hp value is set for the whole class:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos_x = self.rect.x = random.randrange(35, screen_width - 35)
        self.pos_y = self.rect.y = random.randrange(35, screen_height - 135)

        self.hp = 3
```

Here's the bullet-hitting-a-zombie collision code:

```
for bullet in bullet_list:
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, zombie_list, False)
            for i in block_hit_list:
                zombie.hp -= 1
                bullet.kill()
                if self.hp <= 0:
                    pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, zombie_list, True)
                    bullet.kill()
                    score += 100
```

Comment: In the code you provide, `hp` *is an instance attribute*. So what's your question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Enemy` class is fine. Since you use `self.hp = 3`, `hp` is already an instance attribute as you want.

But your collision code seems wrong. I guess it should be something like

```
for bullet in bullet_list:
    # get a list of zombies that are hit
    zombies = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, zombie_list, False)

    # for each of those zombies
    for z in zombies:
        z.hp -= 1         # reduce the health of that very zombie
        bullet.kill()
        if z.hp <= 0:     # and if the health is <= 0
            z.kill()      # remove it 
            score += 100  # and get some points
```

Comment: Sloth my man you've done it again. Thanks man! I realize now that when I had `for z in zombies: zombie.hp -= 1` I was changing the entire zombie class hp but when I put `z.hp -= 1` then it changes that specific object in the zombie list. Thank you so much! I feel so silly, that was kinda obvious haha my bad!